# breaking integral into 2 sub integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

is it possible to break $$\oint_{|z|=2}\tan(z)+\frac{e^z}{z-4}\,dz$$ into $$\oint_{|z|=2}\tan(z)\,dz+\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{z-4}\,dz$$ or these kinds of integral doesn't support this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\int_{C}f(z)\,dz=\int_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$$
if $\gamma(t)$ is a parametrization of our path from $a$ to $b$. Now we have a definite integral that splits into
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt=\int_{a}^{b}Re(f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t))dt+i\int_{a}^{b}Im(f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t))dt$$
Now we have the sum of two real valued integrals, for which we know that $$\int_{a}^{b}(\lambda f(x)+\mu g(x))dx=\int_{a}^{b}\lambda f(x)dx+\int_{a}^{b}\mu g(x))dx$$
So yes, you can do that with that type of integrals as well